energy management on suspend
I am testing on a Lenovo ThinkPad E16 Gen 2. When I suspend my Ubuntu 24.04.1 (Linux 6.8.0-50-generic kernel) the battery discharged about 15% after 10 hours since the last update (or I found this in last days). I have dual boot with Windows 11 so I tested with Windows, too. There is 0% lost along 3 hours suspend. What can I do to prevent discharge on Ubuntu?

WiFi power save is on.
The processor fan is turned off when I suspend the notebook

I checked the suspend system messages with the following results:
sudo journalctl -b|grep -i suspend

dec 25 20:46:44 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu kernel: Low-power S0 idle used by default for system suspend
dec 25 20:46:44 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu kernel: nvme 0000:05:00.0: platform quirk: setting simple suspend
dec 25 20:48:07 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu systemd-logind[2119]: Suspending...
dec 25 20:48:07 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu ModemManager[2389]: <msg> [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
dec 25 20:48:08 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend...
dec 25 20:48:08 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu systemd-sleep[5920]: Performing sleep operation 'suspend'...
dec 25 20:48:08 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
dec 25 20:48:17 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
dec 25 20:48:17 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu systemd-sleep[5920]: System returned from sleep operation 'suspend'.
dec 25 20:48:17 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu kernel: PM: suspend exit
dec 25 20:48:17 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
dec 25 20:48:17 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu systemd[1]: Finished systemd-suspend.service - System Suspend.
dec 25 20:48:17 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu systemd[1]: Reached target suspend.target - Suspend.
dec 25 20:48:17 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu systemd-logind[2119]: Operation 'suspend' finished.
dec 25 20:48:17 lenovoe16g2-ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped target suspend.target - Suspend.


I added memory deep sleep to grub config, but it doesn't helped for me.
